# Plotting multiple columns with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I need to plot the following dataset in the same graph.

```
Bin1,Bin2,Bin3,Cat
4,3,5,S
6,4,5,M
3,5,4,M
1,4,5,M
 ,5, ,M
```

In each bin, first data point belongs to a different category than the rest. (So I added the Cat column)

I need to plot these as points (different colors for the different categories)

Following lines of code achieve what I need for a single bin

```
p <- ggplot(data,aes(Bin1,1))
p + geom_point(aes(color=Cat, size=Cat))
```

How do I do this for the  entire dataset ?

---

Here is a related question?

What if I need to use a bunch of columns to color the points. Color Bin1 points according to Cat1 and so on..

```
Bin1,Cat1,Bin2,Cat2
4,S,5,S
6,L,5,M
3,M,4,L
1,M,5,L
    3,M
```

How do I do this??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(melt(df, id.vars = "Cat"), aes(value, variable, colour = Cat)) + 
geom_point(size = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: Added a related question to the original question..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just melt the data.frame and plot it.

```
library(reshape2)

dataM <- melt(data, id.vars = "Cat")

p <- ggplot(dataM, aes(value, variable, colour = Cat, size  = Cat) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I want.. I need Bin No 1,2,3 on the Y axis and data points on the X axis. Need to use same set of colors and shapes for all bins in the dataset.

Comment: I edited my answer, it wasn't clear to me what you wanted from your Q.

Comment: Added a related question to original question..